# html validation error for html lang attribute

Tags: html, validation, attributes, lang

I am getting this error message:

> This document appears to be Lorem ipsum text but the html start tag has lang="en". Consider using lang="zxx" (or variant) instead.
>
> From line 5, column 32; to line 5, column 47
>
> html lang="en"
>
> For further guidance, consult Tagging text with no language, Declaring the overall language of a page and Choosing language tags.
>
> If the HTML checker has misidentified the language of this document, please file an issue report or send e-mail to report the problem.
>
> for html lang = "en" attribute

What should I do right now ?

Answer (score 5):

You're using lorem ipsum, which isn't English. Changing the language attribute to `zxx` should fix the validation warning. `zxx` is used when the language is unknown.

Your options:

1. Change `en` to `zxx` --- html `lang="zxx"`
2. Replace lorem ipsum with English dummy text and keep `en`
3. Ignore the warning until you update your page with real content

https://github.com/validator/validator/issues/321

Answer (score 2):

Use `lang="zxx"` to tagging text with no language.

You can use lang attributes in your block and inline elements like `<p>`, `<span>`, `<a>` etc., as long as your page is in English, for example:

```
<p lang="zxx">Lorem ipsum</p>
```

Webpage in English language:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    ...
    <!-- Elements in English: without lang attribute -->
    <p>Hello World</p>
    ...
    <!-- Elements in other languages: with lang attribute -->
    <p lang="de">Hallo Welt</p>
    ...
    <!-- Elements with Unknown language: with lang (zxx) attribute -->
    <p lang="zxx">Lorem ipsum</p>
    ...
    <!-- Mixed -->
    <p>This Page contains <span lang="zxx">Lorem ipsum</span> Text!</p>
    <p>German Words like: <span lang="de">Hallo, Welt</span></p>
    <p lang="zxx">Lorem ipsum <span lang="en">Hello World</span></p>
    <p>The language is in <span title="Spanish" lang="es">Español</span></p>
    ...
</body>
</html>
```

Or HTML language declaration for unknown language:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="zxx">
<head>
    <title>Lorem ipsum</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    ...
    <!-- don't need lang attribute -->
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    ...
    <!-- The language is known -->
    <p lang="en" title="English">Hello World</p>
    <p lang="de" title="German">Hallo Welt</p>
    ...
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's working.. but what is the use? Is there any issues?