# Difference between lang="" and lang="zxx"

Tags: html, lang, html4

Is there any difference between lang="" and lang="zxx"? And are they compatible with both HTML4 and HTML5?

Comment: give an example.

Comment: This seems to explain it all pretty well: https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-no-language

Comment: Relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40210470/html-validation-error-for-html-lang-attribute

Comment: @sp00m: thanks, I was there, but for some reason I missed that part about lang="", thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

zxx is used when the  language is unknown

Comment: or irrelevant. while still wanting to pass html validation checks